# MongoDB Win service shuts down after logoff the windows session

Tags: windows, mongodb, service

I am using MongoDB under following environment

- MongoDB x86 2.2
- Windows 2003 x86

and installed as windows service using the service install functionality provided out of the box.

Now service is install properly and it is working fine too.

but issue is when logging off the windows session, the MongoDB services stops.
and it prints in the log file as in link : http://pastebin.com/fkLbJ4Sv

Any solutions regarding this or i am missing something

**Update:**

> I tried to replicate this with Windows 7 and windows 2008 R2, it is
>   not causing an issue.
>
> Seems like this issue only in the Windows 2003 Server

Comment: found some observation from log files, service installed is listening onto some events such as CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT and it is running as something into console as log saying-- [consoleTerminate]

Comment: This question is also being discussed on the [mongodb-user discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/d3c831f271c79b1d).

Comment: @Stennie this is me only posting there.

Comment: Indeed you started the discussion on mongodb-user; I just noted the link here since there are comments/details that won't be reflected on StackOverflow ;-).

Comment: @Stennie ok, you saved my time for linking same, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is now ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7031, currently unresolved.